# If Nirvana is unconditional then why is it not happening now?

Tags: nirvana

It is said that Nirvana is unconditional i.e there are no conditions for it to happen. If so then why is Nirvana not happening now? Is my wish or suitability a condition for it happen?

Comment: It is happening now, you are just not being mindful and aware enough to realize it.

Comment: What is the proof it is happening now ? I am suffering everyday. Suffering is opposite of Nirvana.

Comment: Asking for proof of nibbana is like a blind man asking for proof of light which is all around him, he just needs to open the eyes and the process of opening eyes is the Dhamma.

Comment: That means experience of Nibbana is conditional. Conditioned upon suitability of my eyes.

Comment: Does the other question on nibbana not answer this?

Comment: Somebody just asked it, what is nibbana?

Comment: Some patience also...with some time...suffering will lessen and lessen...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gl0Lyxi8nbQ

Comment: You are saying experience of Nibbana is conditional and therefore if those conditions are removed then experience of Nibbana will be lost. If Nibbana is permanent then the condition used to achieve it must also have become permanent. Because if conditions are impermanent then experience of Nibbana will vanish one day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82641/discussion-between-friedrick-nietzsche-and-dheeraj-verma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If so then why is Nirvana not happening now?

Nibbana is an existing reality. Its obscured by defilements just like a blue sky obscured by clouds. Insight-meditation and Jhana allows for the practitioner to experience and eventually attain Nibbana.

> Is my wish or suitability a condition for it happen?

A wholesome intention is the start but not enough in and of itself. It must be followed up by practice. We ourselves must do the work, ie. working for purification of body, mind and conduct.

I highly recommend reading the article [*"Nibbana"*](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books16/Bhikkhu_Bodhi-Nibbana.pdf), by Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi.

Answer (score 2):

@ Dheeraj Verma, you are continuously try to conceptualize the Nibbana. your inner mentality is keep you driving to fulfill your desire to feel,see or experience the Nibbana.Isn't it? I had this issue earlier. it's like blacksmith build his own cage more stronger and stronger and become prisoner in his own cage ignorantly. You build strong concepts,ideologies and conditions ultimately you will end up with depression and misery. this is not the path. I have faced this harsh reality and just cross the line. Just observe the nature and try to realize. Just carefully refer the life of Buddha how he observe the nature and then slowly and gently try to realize. Nirvana here and now. Metta!

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer with an analogy:

Suppose there is a small hill covering a much larger hill obscuring it from view. An energetic, skillful young woman climbs the hill (Stream Entry). She is happy about her achievement but suddenly realizes she has a lot more work left. She eventually climbs the larger hill and attains a magnificent view of the valley like never before. Her perspective of the surroundings has changed forever.

In this story, the larger hill was always there. But, she needed to create conditions to reach the summit.

Comment: Ok. Now suppose she climbs down the hill will the magnificent view of valley not be lost ? Unless she remains forever on top of the hill the view of the valley will be lost. That is the condition.

Comment: @DheerajVerma it is just a similitude. You still being with condition, so he just give you the similitude of conditions to show you the perspective of nibbāna, which is no condition.

Comment: I can ask the question without simile. If conditions led to discovery of Nibbana then when those conditions are lost the experience of Nibbana will be also lost unless those conditions which led to Nibbana became permanent.

Comment: @DheerajVerma Well, similes are never perfect. I see it more like Nibbana being a pond (always there) and plants obstructing the way to the pond, the clearly seeing of the (bodem of the) pond. The plants being the hindrances and  defilements. When you have gotten rid of all the plants including the roots (!), they will never ever be able to hide Nibbana again. Something like that. 4NT: when suffering ceases, Nibbana will be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is like this sort of question,
Think about a kid which is just started school, and he asks about this kind a questions from the his own class mates,

- What is **Quantum Physics** ?
- What is **Universe** ?
- What is **General Relativity** ?
- Can you explain **wave function** ?
- can you explain **Schrodinger equation**

i point out this questions cause even some collage students can not explain these for exact point, those who can will not explain it to those kids because there at another level far away from the kids. So for this example just think how can kid knows about all that things one may be willing to be lawyer, business men .etc and only one kid will be a scientist how will answer those questions soon he became one. Yet he also can not answer those questions, except he can say this book has this and that man said this, kind of answers.

so i'm telling here is if some one is on the path to achieve something extraordinary and noble,without going along that path see for our self is better, rather ask someone from same level,and it is useless. Because they maybe also on the path to achieve it, so their knowledge about it will also unclear not the exact.

Only possible explanation for **Nirvana** is we can not explain it. By following eight noble path anyone can see what exactly **Nirvana** is.

Hope you could understand.

Answer (score 1):

Nirvana is suchness (tathata). This is why Buddha is called Tathagata. Suchness is when you don't crave for anything to be different than it is now. So, regardless of how your situation changes, you take it "as it is", at every moment in time. This is why Nirvana is called "unconditional", because it does not depend on the circumstances moment-by-moment.

But first you have to reach that state when you don't crave for anything to be different than it is. If you still have craving/aversion then Nirvana is not happening.

It's really simple.

Comment: Is acceptance of now as it is called Nirvana?

Comment: Pretty much. Well, "is-ness" is called Nirvana - and acceptance is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

[The dependent origination](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=12&item=153&items=6&eng=accesstoinsight_ntbb) are **the cycle of happening/cessation conditions**.

What is the **dependent origination**?

It is **every true things**, except **nibbāna**.

What is **nibbāna**?

It is the truth which is the **opposite** side of the dependent origination, **the opposite side of the cycle of happening/cessation conditions**. ์Nibbāna never has happening/cessation conditions. The conditions can know nibbāna, but they can't let nibbāna arise or vanish.

Why we **can't see** nibbāna by thinking like the noble ones can do?

Because we still having **the wrong understood about the dependent origination**, [diṭṭhi-clinging](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/25469/10100), so we can't daily understand&discover&make cessation of the truth's root conditions, avijjā&taṇhā&all-unwholesome. **Therefore we can't see nibbāna like the noble ones can do.**

**How to see** nibbāna?

[Observe sīla, meditate samādhi and vipassanā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=18&A=2003&eng=accesstoinsight_than) until enlightened.

---

The popular question about nibbāna already answered in [Ekādasamo paricchedo Nibbānaniddeso](http://www.tipitaka.org/romn/cscd/abh06t.nrf11.xml) of  abhidhammāvatāra.

There also are many  aspects of nibbāna in Abhi. [Kathāvatthu](https://suttacentral.net/kv) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Dhamma is said to be timeless.

I think the Dhamma, specifically the first three noble truths, says that it's suffering (not nibbana) that's conditioned:

1. Truth of suffering
2. Truth of the cause/origin of suffering
3. Truth of the cessation of suffering

Nibbana is the cessation of suffering,

I suppose you could see the fourth truth (the noble eightfold path) as a cause of (or condition for) nibbana, but instead it's described as a path:

4. Truth of the path leading to the cessation of suffering

**Is my wish or suitability a condition for it happen**

The condition for (or path towards) the cessation of suffering is the abandoning of conditions which cause suffering; those conditions (according to the second noble truth), to be abandoned, are basically "craving" in various forms:

> 2. this is the dukkha·samudaya ariya·sacca: this taṇhā leading to rebirth, connected with desire and enjoyment, finding delight here or there, that is to say: kāma-taṇhā, bhava-taṇhā and vibhava-taṇhā

I think that, here (i.e. in [SN 56.11](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/sutta/samyutta/maha/sn56-011.html)) and elsewhere, it's taught that causes or origins of suffering include:

- Self-views, including identification with and attachment to the aggregates, even pride/conceit
- Sensual desires and attachment
- Aversion (maybe like 'desire' but the other side of the coin), also called "anger" or "hatred"
- Ignorance (as a result of which, wrong views and wrong attachments)
- Immorality
- Not just actual cravings, and attachments, but "[tendencies](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/15759/254)" too

Conversely there are many factors which can help on the path.

- I'm not sure that merely "wishing" for something is sufficient to make it so -- e.g. [SN 42.6](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.006.than.html):

  > Very well, then, headman, I will question you on this matter. Answer as you see fit. What do you think: There is the case where a man is one who takes life, steals, indulges in illicit sex; is a liar, one who speaks divisive speech, harsh speech, & idle chatter; is greedy, bears thoughts of ill-will, & holds to wrong views. Then a great crowd of people, gathering & congregating, would pray, praise, & circumambulate with their hands palm-to-palm over the heart [saying,] '**May this man, at the break-up of the body, after death, reappear in a good destination, the heavenly world!**' What do you think: would that man — because of the prayers, praise, & circumambulation of that great crowd of people — at the break-up of the body, after death, reappear in a good destination, the heavenly world?"
  >
  > "No, lord."
  >
  > "Suppose a man were to throw a large boulder into a deep lake of water, and a great crowd of people, gathering & congregating, would pray, praise, & circumambulate with their hands palm-to-palm over the heart [saying,] 'Rise up, O boulder! Come floating up, O boulder! Come float to the shore, O boulder!' What do you think: would that boulder — because of the prayers, praise, & circumambulation of that great crowd of people — rise up, come floating up, or come float to the shore?"
  >
  > "No, lord."

  See also [How do you reach Nirvana when you are craving Nirvana?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/29035/254) (for some analysis of wishing, of desire).

  But the second factor of the noble eightfold path is "right intention", "right resolve" ... a right or effective form (or result) of desire.
- It may begin with hearing the Dhamma, with taking refuge ... with morality (including e.g. generosity), with [spiritual friendship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaly%C4%81%E1%B9%87a-mittat%C4%81)
- See also e.g. the [Wings to Awakening](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/wings/index.html) or [Bodhipakkhiyādhammā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhipakkhiy%C4%81dhamm%C4%81)

It's quite a lot of Dhamma and difficult to eradicate thoroughly ... so you might find it helpful to remember simplified versions like "suffering and cessation". Or just the first two noble truths: i.e. that "suffering is caused".